# Cardinality of lower triangular Matrix contains rational number

Tags: matrices

Can anybody explain what is the **cardinality** of lower triangular Matrix contains rational number and size of matrix is lower than $7$?

I don't have any idea where to start and what to do?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense to me: it looks like a collection of math words strung together almost randomly.  Where did you get this question?  Do you understand it yourself?  Please try rephrasing and/or giving an example.   If you mean "What is the cardinality of the set of all $n \times n$ matrices which are lower triangular and have rational entries, as $n$ ranges over all positive integers less than $7$", then the answer is that this a countable set, so of cardinality $\aleph_0$.